# EF5 one to one or zero relationship with different keys

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

The real world scenario is deeds, mortgages, etc. all of which are referred to as "instruments" in a county register and recorder's office.

I have the following entities for this scenario.

```cs
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public virtual RequestInstrument RequestInstrument { get; set; }
}

public class RequestInstrument
{
    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    //This column is also unique and it is enforced in the database
    //but it is not the primary key
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
}

public class Instrument
{
    [Key]
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual RequestInstrument RequestInstrument { get; set; }
}
```

Requests are made for instruments.  Some instruments are recorded without a request.  Not all requests turn into recorded instruments.  That is why requests and instruments have independent primary keys.  When a request does turn into a recorded instrument, there is one and only one request for the related instrument and vice versa.

As best I can tell, EF only supports 1 to 1..0 relationships if both tables have the same key.  I guess this is really a 1..0 to 1..0 relationship if there is such a thing.

Is there a way to pull off the above model using independent primary keys?

Comment: So if RequestId is not the primary key then does RequestInstruments have a composite key like say, RequestId and InstrumentId make it unique?

Comment: You say, "Requests are made for instruments." Can a request exist without an Instrument? Also, you mention a "Recorded Instrument". What is that?

Comment: In RequestInstruments, RequestId by itself is unique.  InstrumentId by itself is also unique.  Either by themselves could be primary keys.  BTW, the only reason I have this intermediate cross linking table is because SQL Server does not permit multiple null values in a unique index.

Comment: @Rufus A request can exist without an instrument because not all requests graduate to become instruments.  A recorded instrument is just a more descriptive name for instrument.  Sorry for switching nomenclature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, Entity Framework only supports 1:1 or 1 to 0..1 relationships with shared primary keys.  The reasons is that EF does not understand or support unique constraints.  So, even though you have a unique constraint in your database, EF does not know that, and as such it cannot guarantee that RequestInstrument.InstrumentId is unique.

If you need to keep this data model, then the best you can do is 1 to many, where you just assume a single item in your many collection.  It's not ideal, but that's the only way to make it work.

Entity Framework 6.x does support unique indexes, and there has been some talk of enhancing the EF model to utilize this for 1:1 support, but as of yet that hasn't materialized.

Comment: This solution is certainly better than not having the relationship in the model which is where I'm currently at.